# Count entries and store as field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following structure in my DB and I need to count "Tripduration" for all the childs and save it under "Tripcount", since I have an entry for the duration for every trip:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "Tripcount": "This should be 5",
    "Trips": [
        {
            "EndStationID": 2,
            "Tripduration": [
                43,
                50,
                45
            ]
        },
        {
            "EndStationID": 3,
            "Tripduration": [
                52
            ]
        },
        {
            "EndStationID": 4,
            "Tripduration": [
                34
            ]
        }
```

I have the following query, however it always returns 0. I am new to the MongoDB syntax and was hoping that someone sees why it returns 0:

```
db.test.aggregate( 
  { 
    $group: { 
      _id:   {"StationID": "$Start Station ID", "EndStationID": "$End Station ID"}, 
      durations: {$addToSet: "$Trip Duration" },
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.StationID",
      Tripcount: {$sum: "durations"},
      Trips: { $addToSet: { EndStationID: "$_id.EndStationID", Tripduration: "$durations"} } 
    } 
  } 
)
```

Comment: @s.s Is shown, first code block on the top of the question. I just need to update the Tripcount field.

Comment: Ok what does the initial document look like?

Comment: @s.s Is also provided exactly there. It's all there already. Just need to update the Tripcount field, which should be the amount of tripdurations as shown.

Comment: Just wanted to be sure I understand. One last question: What is your mongod version?

Comment: @s.s I appreciate that. It's the latest, 3.4.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the Aggregation Framework.

You need to apply the `$add` expression to the array of "Tripduration" `$size` and combine the value using the `$reduce` operator.

Of course to get the array of "Tripduration"'s size you need to use the `$map` array operator

```
db.trip.aggregate(    
    [
       {
          "$addFields":{
             "Tripcount":{
                "$reduce":{
                   "input":{
                      "$map":{
                         "input":"$Trips",
                         "in":{
                            "$size":"$$this.Tripduration"
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "initialValue":0,
                   "in":{
                      "$add":[
                         "$$value",
                         "$$this"
                      ]
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    ]
)
```

Make the change persistent in your collection, simple add the `$out` pipeline to the stage

```
{ "$out": "trip" }
```

But note that this will overwrite you collection or create a new one

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$reduce` to concat arrays followed by `$size` on 3.4 version.

```
db.test.aggregate(
    [{
        $addFields: {
            "Tripcount": {
                $size: {
                    $reduce: {
                        input: "$Trips.Tripduration",
                        initialValue: [],
                        in: {
                            $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

Reference : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/

Comment: Nice use of `$concatArrays`  there. But note that this will be inefficient with large array.